# Update DGV after inserting a row

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I insert a selected row at the end of my database by pressing a button when a row is selected with the following code which works fine:

```
Dim conn_veko As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Gxxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxx;  Integrated Security=TRUE")
Dim insert_cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.Insert", conn)
Dim i As Integer = DGV.CurrentRow.Index
conn.Open()
With BenutzerTabelle_SelectDataGridView.Rows(i)
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V1", .Cells(0).Value)
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V2", .Cells(1).Value)
End With
insert_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

The record gets inserted in the database but i have to restart my programm to see the record in my dgv. 
People suggested (in my google search) to try dgv.refresh() and DataSet1.AcceptChanges() but it didnt helped. I have the following SP on my SQL-Server that might help but i dont know how to use it.

```
CREATE Procedure Tabupdate
@v1 date
@v2 int
as
Begion
Set NoCount on
UPDATE Table
SET
v1 = @v1,
v2 = @v2
where @v3 = 3
END
```

Could anyone please help me getting this to work?

Comment: Try to databind again your grid after insert.

Comment: I am missing something here. You take the values for the insert command from the grid, but, you says, that you cannot see the values. So could you explain what are the values that you don't see?

Comment: @Steve: I select a row, click a button and should see the data i selected in the new row at the bottom of the grid. But i dont see the data there.

Comment: @kostas ch.: I really new with this. I created everything with drag and drop. Add new element, drag the data adapter. Use the wizard and so on. Is what you suggest still possible with such a background, i just wanna know before i start working into it and it is not possible.

Comment: Where parameter for @v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill your grid again, however your doing it now. Just do it after the insert, this will pick up the new data.

Comment: Thanks, it is working! Me.TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Table)

Comment: Your welcome, I just didn't have Any code you were using to fill it or I would have put that down.